# How to change font-size Text with <input type= range> using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have HTML,I want to change font-size text "...." with input type=range when using Jquery

> Html

```
<div class="font-size"><p>Font size:</p><output for="fader" id="fontsize">50</output></div>
<input class="none" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" id="fader" step="1" onchange="outputbox01(value)">
<text id="v-28" class="changeMe" y="0.8em" fill="white" stroke="black" stroke-width="0" transform="translate(35,20.5) ">This is the text you want to change the font size</text>
```

JavaScript

> `function outputbox01(vol) {
>       document.querySelector('#fontsize').value = vol;
>   }`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#fontsize").change(function () {
    $('#v-28').css("font-size", $(this).val() + "px");
});
```

});

thank U for watching.

Comment: `<text>` isn't a valid HTML element; is this SVG? If so, it needs the appropriate tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first you are using wrong **selector** in jQuery event handler for listening to change event.

And in you case (i.e **range**) change event is triggered only after the mouse is released , so you can use `input` event to track the **range** change.

```
$("#fader").on("input change",function () {
        $('#v-28').css("font-size", $(this).val() + "px");
});
```

### Here is the [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y9RxH/)

P.S

And if you want to use slider plugin , you could definitely try [Slider | jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/slider/).

Hope this help your cause.

Comment: Thank U.I was successful :)

Comment: Can you help me,again.Thank you :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853488/how-to-change-size-and-coordinates-of-box-with-input-type-number-when-using-jq

Answer (score 3):

I know the question is asking about jQuery, but for anyone who finds this question while searching, here's an answer that doesn't use jQuery.

```
<input type="range" min="12" max="72" value="16" id="font-size" />
```

Then the following JavaScript:

```
var slider = document.getElementById('font-size');

slider.addEventListener('input', function() {
    var size = slider.value;
    // this sets the body's font size property, but you can set whatever you need to
    document.body.style.fontSize = size + "px";
});
```

The `input` event is raised during dragging of the slider. The `change` event is only raised when dragging is completed. Use whichever you prefer.