# How to change size and coordinates of `rect` box with <input type=number> when using jQuery/JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I have a `rect` box (`svg`). The code:

```
<div class="basicShapes">
    <svg id="basicShapes" width="230" height="173">
        <g id="basicRect" class="basicRect"  fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="none" transform="translate(20,23)">
            <g id="v-26" class="rotatable" transform="rotate(0,45,27)">
                <g id="v-29" class="scalable" transform="scale(1.8,1.8)">
                    <rect id="v-27" fill="#27AE60" stroke="black" width="50" height="30" rx="2" ry="2">
                </g>
                <text id="v-28" class="changeMe" y="0.8em" fill="white" stroke="black" stroke-width="0" transform="translate(35,20.5) ">text</text>
            </g>
        </g>
   </svg>
</div>
```

HTML: `<input type="number"/>.`

I want to change size and coordinates of `rect` (`svg`).

```
<div class="content-box03">
  <p>width:</p>   <!-- width of box -->
  <input type="number" id="mywidth" value="0">
  <p>height:</p>   <!-- height of box -->
  <input type="number" id="myheight" value="0">
  <p>x:</p>   <!-- coordinates Ox -->
  <input type="number" id="my-x" value="0">
  <p>y:</p>    <!-- Coordinates Oy -->
  <input type="number" id="my-y" value="0">
</div>
```

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `onchange` attributes to your `input` elements:

```
<input type="number" id="mywidth" onchange="changeW()">
<p>height:</p>
<input type="number" id="myheight" onchange="changeH()">
<p>x:</p>
<input type="number" id="my-x" onchange="changeX()">
<p>y:</p>
<input type="number" id="my-y" onchange="changeY()">
```

And write handlers that affect the `rect` element's attributes:

```
var changeW = function() {
  var width = $('#mywidth').val();
  var $v27 = $('#v-27');
  $v27.attr('width', width);
};

var changeH = function() {
  var height = $('#myheight').val();
  var $v27 = $('#v-27');
  $v27.attr('height', height);
};

var changeX = function() {
  var xPos = $('#my-x').val();
  var $v27 = $('#v-27');
  $v27.attr('x', xPos);
};

var changeY = function() {
  var yPos = $('#my-y').val();
  var $v27 = $('#v-27');
  $v27.attr('y', yPos);
};
```

**Working Demo http://jsbin.com/xozome/5/edit**

Alternatively…

Add a `button` that can handle an `onclick` event:

```
<button type="submit" onclick="process(event)">Submit</button>
```

Then write a function to process the user's input:

```
var process = function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var width = $('#mywidth').val();
  var height = $('#myheight').val();
  var xPos = $('#my-x').val();
  var yPos = $('#my-y').val();

  var $v27 = $('#v-27');
  $v27.attr('width', width);
  $v27.attr('height', height);
  $v27.attr('x', xPos);
  $v27.attr('y', yPos);

};
```

**Working Demo at http://jsbin.com/xozome/4/edit**

Answer (score 0):

You can use `prop` method of jQuery to set the value of `height` and `width`. And also you can use `position` method to set the position.

And then you can add input or change event listener to track the required value ...

```
$("#mywidth,#myheight ,#my-x ,#my-y").on("change input",function(){
    var coordinateX = $("#my-x").val();  
    var coordinateY = $("#my-y").val();  
    var height = $("#myheight").val();
    var width = $("#mywidth").val();
    if(coordinateX !=0 && coordinateY !=0  && height!=0 && width!=0){
    $("#basicShapes").css({position:"absolute", left:coordinateX,top:coordinateY});
        $("#v-27").prop("width", width);
        $("#v-27").prop("height", height);
    }
});
```

### And here is the [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MfegM/1703/)

P.S

I am not good at CSS , so you need to work the CSS part for making the input form relative to the rectangle.

Good Luck.